# React-Router: Apply logic to component before navigating to a different route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Is it possible to apply logic to a component before navigating to a different route?

For example, my component looks something like this:

```
  class Example extends React.Component {

    //Handles logic for when user leaves page
    handlePageExit = () => {
        console.log("Leaving page...");
    }

    //Set onBeforeUnload event listener so handlePageExit function is called when user closes or refreshes page
    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.addEventListener("onbeforeunload", this.handlePageExit);
    }

    //This hook is called when page exits or is refreshed 
    //It will remove event listener when 
    //However, it wont be called when user changes to a new route
    componentWillMount = () => {
        window.removeEventListener("onbeforeunload", this.handlePageExit)
    }

    //There's no react life cycle hook I can use to call HandlePageLogic when user navigates to a new route to remove event listener or apply other logic...

    render(){
        return(
          <div /> //Not relevant to question
        )
    }
}
```

I'm trying to apply logic such as removing event listeners before the page is navigated to the new route.

I've tried using life cycle methods such as `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUnmount`, and `componentShouldUpdate` to insert logic before the component is unmounted however they don't seem to be invoked when navigating to a new page.

Does anyone know where or how I can insert logic in between a route change in react-router v4?

Thank you.

Comment: By the way if you want to remove some event listener you need to do it in componentWillUnmount not in componentWillMount like you did.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is.
You need to add a change listener to you react router history object.

To do this add in your componentDidMount that has the history prop:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.listen(this.onRouteChange.bind(this));
  }

onRouteChange(route) {
//route.pathname = Your next route

//Handle what you need to do here
//if you need to redirect you can do this
     this.props.history.replace({pathname: '/desiredRoute'});
  }
```

Comment: +1 This fixed glitches for me. I've used to scoll to top in a react hook when pathname changed (so in a component lifecycle). Now I''ve used iNovelletto solution, all seems fine!

Comment: What is the equivalent for React Router 6?