# React Routing: Detect route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having trouble detecting route changes with React Router v5. <del>The desire is, when the route changes I want output a console.log.</del> The desire is, when the route changes I want output that route in a console.log in the App component (as shown in the code below) so I can then set a variable in App.js based on the route.

Package versions:

```
"dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.12.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
}
```

This is the App.js code where my router is currently located:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, NavLink } from "react-router-dom"
import "./App.css";
import AdminDashboard from "./pages/AdminDashboard"
import UserList from "./pages/UserList"

function App() {

    const routeChange = () => {
        console.log("foo!")
        console.log(window.location.pathname)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Router onChange={routeChange}>
                <NavLink exact={true} className="nav-link" to="/AdminDashboard">Admin Dashboard</NavLink>
                <NavLink exact={true} className="nav-link" to="/UserList">User List</NavLink>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/AdminDashboard" component={AdminDashboard} exact />
                    <Route path="/UserList" component={UserList} exact />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592143/12461764)? and remove that `onChange` event on the `Router` tag it's pointless.

Comment: props.history is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping with `withRouter` works fine, but from react-router5, they have hooks to avoid it. so that we don't inject unwanted props to the component.
In this case, you could make use of `useLocation` hook.

If you try to run `const location = useLocation()` inside **App.js** you'll get: `"TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined" on line 712 of react-router/esm/react-router.js`. But you can access `useLocation()` inside a child component (e.g. **Route.js**) and pass the location back up to the parent via a prop function `setPathname()` `<Router>` must be in a parent component in order for `useLocation()` to work.

### App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink} from "react-router-dom"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
    
    const setPathname = (pathname) => {
        console.log("**", pathname)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <NavLink exact={true} className="nav-link" to="/AdminDashboard">Admin Dashboard</NavLink>
            <NavLink exact={true} className="nav-link" to="/UserList">User List</NavLink>            
            <Router onChange={routeChange}>
                <Routes setPathname={setPathname} />
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}

export default App
```

### Routes.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Router, Route, Switch, NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
import AdminDashboard from "./pages/AdminDashboard"
import UserList from "./pages/UserList"

function Routes(props) {
    const location = useLocation()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("*", location.pathname)
        props.setPathname(location.pathname)
    },[location])

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/AdminDashboard" component={AdminDashboard} exact />
                <Route path="/UserList" component={UserList} exact />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default Routes
```

The result of this will give you two console logs. One from the child Routes.js and one from the parent App.js. Then you can set your variable based on the `pathname` in either component, as needed.

1. `*, [pathname]`
2. `**, [pathname]`

Comment: This is cleaner and more intuitive than my answer =)

Comment: I've tried this method, but when I run "const location = useLocation()" I get an error:  "TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined" on line 712 of react-router/esm/react-router.js

Comment: Its because the react-router context isn't set in that component. Since its the <Router> component that sets the context you could use useHistory in a sub-component, but not in that one. Sorry, i didn't notice this before. Updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Moving the routes to a child component and then sending those back to the parent via a props function works well. I clarified this, and added information about the error I mentioned in a previous comment inside the answer which edit is awaiting community approval.

Comment: how to get before and after changed?

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had to make some minor adjustments: App.js: the `onChange` prop for `Router` did not seem to be used so I removed it. In Routes.js: `import React, { useEffect } from "react"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tie the router into the component using `withRouter`..

> withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: yep that's one of the options as well either operating on history prop or using the hook

Answer (score -1):

assign a callback on `props.history.listen` the history property will detect changes and fire your callback

Comment: props.history is undefined.

Comment: history prop is inside every component passed to Route so I'm not really sure what is the case, you might try ```import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'; const history = createBrowserHistory()``` and assign the listen function that history